# Could not resolve view with name in java spring .jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is link to project:https://github.com/s25866-pj/UserService 
I'm encountering an error while trying to resolve the view 'getAllUsers' in the 'dispatcherServlet'. Here are the details of the error:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'getAllUsers' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'getAllUsers' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1394) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]

I have already checked the following:

- The JSP file 'getAllUsers.jsp' exists in the correct location: 'webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/user/'.
- The controller has the appropriate method for handling the GET request for the path '/getAllUsers' and returning the view name 'getAllUsers'.
- The view resolver configuration in my Spring MVC configuration class is correct with the prefix '/WEB-INF/jsp/' and suffix '.jsp'.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.UserManagment")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/getUser")
    public Optional<UserModel> showUser(@RequestParam Long id){
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public String showAllUser(Model model){
        List<UserModel> users = userService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("users",users);
        return "getAllUsers";
    }

}
```

I would like the page "http://localhost:8081/user/getAllUsers" to show a list of users instead of the Whitelabel Error Page

Answer (score 0):

Since, the view resolver prefix is `/WEB-INF/jsp/`, but the JSP file is located in `/WEB-INF/jsp/user/`, then you should return `"user/getAllUsers"` from the controller method so that the correct file is found based on the prefix and suffix.

Comment: Still the same problem, fixed files that how you write. everwhere is to fix it that but it don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Since your jsp file is in user folder  which is in jsp folder, In view resolver change prefix to

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/user/
```

Instead of using view resolver, you can also add prefix & suffix in application.properties as below

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/user/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```